# How to organize proto file to re-use message if possible?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto

I recently started working with protobuf in my golang project. I created below simple protobuf file. I have three different endpoints.

- `GetLink` takes `CustomerRequest` as an input parameter and returns back `CustomerResponse`
- `GetBulkLinks` takes `BulkCustomerRequest` as an input parameter and returns back `BulkCustomerResponse`
- `StreaLinks` takes `StreamRequest` as an input parameter and returns back `CustomerResponse`

I am wondering if there is any way we can improve below proto file because `CustomerRequest` and `BulkCustomerRequest` has mostly everything in common except `resources` field so there is a duplication. And same goes with `StreamRequest` input parameter as it only takes `clientId` as the input parameter. Is there anything in protocol buffer which can reuse stuff from another message type?

Is there any better or efficient way to organize below proto file which reuses message accordingly?

```
syntax = "proto3";

option go_package = "github.com/david/customerclient/gen/go/data/v1";

package data.v1;

service CustomerService {
  rpc GetLink(CustomerRequest) returns (CustomerResponse) {};
  rpc GetBulkLinks(BulkCustomerRequest) returns (BulkCustomerResponse) {};
  rpc StreaLinks(StreamRequest) returns (CustomerResponse) {};
}

message CustomerRequest {
  int32 clientId = 1;
  string resources = 2;
  bool isProcess = 3;
}

message BulkCustomerRequest {
  int32 clientId = 1;
  repeated string resources = 2;
  bool isProcess = 3;
}

message StreamRequest {
  int32 clientId = 1;
}

message CustomerResponse {
  string value = 1;
  string info = 2;
  string baseInfo = 3;
  string link = 4;
}

message BulkCustomerResponse {
  map<string, CustomerResponse> customerResponse = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there anything in protocol buffer which can reuse stuff from another message type?

[Composition](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#other).

However keep in mind that request and response payloads may change over time. Even if it *looks like* they have something in common today, they may diverge tomorrow. **After all they are used in different RPCs**. Then excessive coupling achieves the opposite effect and becomes technical debt.

Since your schema has literally no more than three fields for each message, I would leave everything as is. Anyway, if you really must, you may consider the following:

- Extract the `GetLink` and `GetBulkLinks` common fields in a separate message and compose with that:

```
message CustomerRequestParams {
  int32 clientId = 1;
  bool isProcess = 2;
}

message CustomerRequest {
  CustomerRequestParams params = 1;
  string resources = 2;
}

message BulkCustomerRequest {
  CustomerRequestParams params = 1;
  repeated string resources = 2;
}
```

- `StreamRequest` looks just fine with repeating `clientId`. Arguably a stream is conceptually different from a unary RPC, so just keep them separated. And it's just one field.

Comment: I forgot to ask you one quick question on this. The way we send request will stay same right irrespective of whether I modify my proto to follow new format or old one which I had in the question?
For bulk - `-d '{"clientId":12345, "resources":["abc", "def", "ghi"]}'`
And for regular `-d '{"clientId":12345, "resources":"abc"}'`. Correct?

Comment: @AndyP if you change the structure of the proto, the request also changes, as JSON is serialized differently. It will probably be `-d '{"params": { "clientId":12345 }, "resources":"abc"}'`